# how to output on ruby, two input in one single line

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need output two different array (or range ) which both of them takes by gets.chomp, one of them a string, the other must be integer. But i dont want to transpoze or i dont want to use zip method. because when i take output one of them in a row, the other might be reverse two or more times.

```
name = $name
num = $num
arr = $arr

puts "num?"
num = gets.chomp.to_i

arr = []
for x in (1..num)
puts "#{x}. name? " #its can be "A" ,"B","C"
name = gets.chomp.to_sym
arr.push (name)
end

for y in (1..100)
  arr.each do |z|
  print y, " " , z, "\n"
  end
end


# i want to outputs like this :
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 A
5 B #reverse time (%5 == 0)
6 A
7 C
8 B
9 A
10 C #reverse time (%5 ==0)
11 A
```

integers dont reverse anytime, but Strings must be reverse...

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a nested loop, you want to pair your integer Range with your name Array, and then loop over the resulting Array of Arrays. In Ruby we can do this using the `#zip` method. Also, because the name array may not fill up the entire Range, we can `#cycle` the name array to convert it to a repeating Enumerator (otherwise, in the example given, 3 through 5 would be paired with `nil`).

```
>> arr = ["John", "Jane"]
>> pairs = (1..5).zip(arr.cycle)
#> [[1, "John"], [2, "Jane"], [3, "John"], [4, "Jane"], [5, "John"]]
>> pairs.each { |integer, name| print "#{integer} #{name}\n" }

1 John
2 Jane
3 John
4 Jane
5 John
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are saying. You can do `pairs = (1..5).zip(arr.reverse.cycle)` if that is helpful.

Comment: well, thanks but indeed, this     #zip method may not useful for my project. Because when i assign a number as a lucky number, for example  if its 4, if number % 4 == 0, my name_array must be  #reverse.  EX.  1-John/   2-Jane/   3-Jack/   4-the lucky John/ 5-Jack/  6-Jane/   7-John/   8 the Lucky Jack/  9-John/ etc.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question to provide clear examples of your inputs and desired outputs. Comments are not an appropriate place to revise your question with a significant new requirement.